# How to get SQL Server Date in its native format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, asp-classic, sql-server-2000

I need to get a Date from an SQL Server Database (SQL Server 2000), the date is stored as such:

```
2009-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

I want to pass this date into a Classic ASP function to use this date in the Database
somewhere else, however when I get the date, it converts in my ASP code to a locale-dependant version, such as:

```
30/09/2009
```

I just want the date as-is as formatting the date so it is correct again seems unnecessary, although if this the only way then fine - is there any way to treat it as string data so it stays like that, so it can be inserted back into the database as the same date, without needing conversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The date is not stored as '2009-09-30 00:00:00.000', it's stored as an 8-byte number where the first 4 bytes are days since jan 1, 1900 and the other 4 bytes are milliseconds in the date.

To get to your format, use convert(varchar, dt, 121). To get the raw format use convert(binary(8), dt)

EDIT: After your question was edited it appears that what you really want is to be able to perform the conversion date -> string -> date.

For that you can use @s = convert(varchar, @dt, 121); @dt = convert(datetime, @s, 121). All other formats would probably work as well, as long as they are consistently applied in both directions.

Comment: I knew that SQL stored the date in its own way, but did not know there was an implicit conversion going on in the Query Analyser, should have checked what the actual format was.

Comment: I thought that was the native format that I stated, not the actual native format - however I was looking for a method to copy dates and thought using the native format would be better in SQL - but since the date is being converted anyway, I will convert it instead.

Comment: Indeed I was passing Dates between functions - wanted to be specific in my question, but should have mentioned that was what I wanted, will mark this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete list of ways: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

As a note, the storage is actually two integers. The first is the number of days before or after Jan 1, 1900 and the other is number of milliseconds since midnight.

Comment: That dateformat list is handy, always having to deal with dates in some way or another - this should be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for this ...

```
'**********************************************************************************************************
'' @SDESCRIPTION:   Gets an independent sql representation for a datetime string standardised by ISO 8601 
'' @DESCRIPTION:    If you want to create a sql statement containing a date query in the where clause,
''                  use this function to create a datetime object.
''                  EXAMPLE:
''                  In Sql Server: Declare @timeTable TABLE (name int, starttime datetime)
''                  In VBScript: sql = "SELECT * FROM timeTable WHERE starttime = " & date.toMsSqlDateFormat(cDate('2007-01-01 15:30:00'))
''                  Results in: SELECT * FROM timeTable WHERE starttime = cast('2006-01-01T15:30:00' as datetime)
''                  NOTE: only for MS SQL Server
'' @PARAM:          dat [date]: the date/time you want to cast
'' @RETURN:         [string] the formatted date string
'**********************************************************************************************************
public function toMsSqlDateFormat(dat)
    if dat = empty then exit function
    toMsSqlDateFormat = "cast('" & year(dat) & "-" & lib.custom.forceZeros(month(dat), 2) & "-" & _
                        padLeft(day(dat), 2, "0") & "T" & padLeft(hour(dat), 2, "0") & ":" & _
                        padLeft(minute(dat), 2, "0") & ":" & padLeft(second(dat), 2, "0") & "' as datetime)"
end function

'******************************************************************************************************************
'' @SDESCRIPTION:   right-aligns a given value by padding left a given character to a totalsize
'' @DESCRIPTION:    example: input: <em>22</em> -> output: <em>00022</em> (padded to total length of 5 with the paddingchar 0)
'' @PARAM:          value [string]: the value which should be aligned right
'' @PARAM:          totalLength [string]: whats the total Length of the result string
'' @PARAM:          paddingChar [string]: the char which is taken for padding
'' @RETURN:         [string] right aligned string.
'******************************************************************************************************************
public function padLeft(value, totalLength, paddingChar)
    padLeft = right(clone(paddingChar, totalLength) & value, totalLength)
end function

public function clone(byVal str, n)
    for i = 1 to n : clone = clone & str : next
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve a date and subsequently use it in another query, you're better off not converting it to a string at all.  In that way you don't need to worry about what formats are used during the conversion.

To do so you need to use parametered queries.  You can google for this, but in classic ASP with VB it will look something like:

```
' Retrieval
...
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
...
objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SomeDate FROM SomeTable"
...
Set objRS = objCommand.Execute
...
dtSomeDate = objRS("SomeDate").Value ' This is a Date object


' Write date to db
...
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
...
objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SomeTable (...,SomeDate) VALUES (...,?)"
Set objParam = objCommand.CreateParameter("SomeDate", adDateTime, adParamInput, dtSomeDate)
...
objCommand.Execute
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have used conversion instead, but passing dates between SQL methods may be useful for something or someone else. Using the CreateParameter to preserve the date format is something I forgot you could do with parameterised queries.